# Regularity of solution of $(-\Delta + w)f = 0$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, mp.mathematical-physics, linear-pde

I am studying the following Schrödinger equation:
$$(-\Delta + w)f = 0$$
which represents a quantum state with zero energy. Here $w$ and $f$ are defined on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. For simplicity, let us assume $w$ is nonnegative, radially symmetric $w(x) = w(|x|) = w(r)$, $r \in (0,\infty)$ and with compact support.

Assume the differential equation above holds in the distribution sense and suppose the solution $f$ is $f \in H^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$. I am actually interested in radially symmetric solutions $f = f(r)$. My question is: how regular the *derivative* of $f$ can be near the origin? I know I can be the case that $\frac{df}{dr}$ goes to infinity as $r \to 0^{+}$, but is there any condition on, say, $r^{2}\frac{df}{dr}$ or some power $r^{n}\frac{df}{dr}$, $n \ge 1$ in which this product goes to zero as $r \to 0^{+}$?

**Edit:** The two important cases for me are: $w \in C^{\infty}$ and $w \in L^{3}(\mathbb{R}^{3})$.

Comment: Which regularity you assume for $w$ near the origin?

Comment: This is a question about linear ODE: you can solve them explicitly and compute the asymptotics at $0$, which will depend on $w$.

Comment: In principle, the only hypothesis on $w$ is that it is $C^{\infty}$, compactly supported, radial and nonnegative.

Comment: If $w$ is smooth, then $f$ is smooth, too, and $f_r(0)=0$.

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune I edited the post with the two most important assumptions for me. The case $w \in L^{3}$ is also relevant.

Comment: @user378654: The last part of your comment is incorrect, $-y''+wy=0$ can not be solved explicitly for a typical $w$. (The actual radial equation has an extra term, but that doesn't change anything.)

Comment: Something is unclear, however. If all functions are defined in the whole space, you multiply by $f$ and integrate $\int |\nabla f|^2+wf^2=0$ which gives $f=0$. This happens also if $w \in L^3$ because $H^1 \subset L^6$ and so $fw \in L^2$

Comment: @GiorgioMetafune: I don't think the OP meant $f\in H^1$ literally, this should be replaced by a local regularity assumption. As you pointed out, we of course can never have $f\in L^2$ because $-\Delta +w$ with compactly supported $w$ doesn't have $0$ as an eigenvalue.

Comment: As pointed out by @user378654, the natural way to ask the question is to ask about the behavior of $f'$ near $r=0$ for solutions of the ODE $-f''-(2/r)f'+wf=0$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: we are in 3D, so $y = rf$ literally solves the equation $-y'' + wy = 0$. (Re [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458534/regularity-of-solution-of-delta-wf-0#comment1187987_458534))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, I interpret the question as asking about the asymptotics of $f'(r)$, $r\to 0+$, for solutions of
$$
-\frac{d^2f}{dr^2} -\frac{2}{r} \frac{df}{dr} + w(r)f(r) = 0 ; \quad\quad\quad\quad (1)
$$
the first two terms are the radial part of $-\Delta$.

I'll show that if $w$ is bounded near $r=0$, then $r^2 df/dr$ will be bounded also (and thus $r^{2+\epsilon} df/dr\to 0$). This covers the case $w\in C^{\infty}$; if we only assume $w\in L^3$, the method still has potential, but things get even more tedious.

The substitution $r=1/t$ brings (1) to the form
$$
-f'' + (w/t^4)f=0 ,
$$
and now we are interested in $df/dr = -t^2f'(t)$ for $t\to\infty$.

This looks promising because $w/t^4\in L^1$ if $w$ is continuous, with room to spare, so perturbation methods should work. We can introduce $Y=(f',f)^t$, so
$$
Y' = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & w/t^4 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} Y .
$$
Write $Y=Y_0u$, with
$$
Y_0 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ t & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
chosen as the fundamental matrix of the unperturbed problem. Now another calculation shows that $u'= O(1/t^2) u$, so the coefficients are still in $L^1$, and Gronwall's inequality shows that $u$ is bounded (in fact, Levinson's theorem shows that $u(t)$ converges as $t\to\infty$).

Unwrapping all this, we find that $f'(t)$ stays bounded, and hence so does $r^2 df/dr=-df/dt$.

Answer (score 2):

regarding the case $f\in L^n$ I can give you some suggestion.

Since $L^n$ is contained in the Morrey space $L^{1,n-1}$ and you have Laplace operator you can say that
$\nabla f $ belongs to BMO and then locally to any $L^p$ class with $1<p<\infty$.

Reference:

Poisson equations and Morrey spaces J. Math. Anal. Appl. 163, (1992)
Theorem 2.7